# Get and order based on most recent entry while in multiple mysql joins

Tags: php, mysql, date, join, max

I have the following statement that finds all the players of a team in the current season. The players are ordered by their handicap. If their handicaps are the same they are ordered by the oldest `added_date`, meaning newer members are lower down the list.

```
SELECT players.playerid_p,
       players.fname, 
       players.sname, 
       players.tel, 
       players.mob, 
       players.email,
       season_players.captain 
FROM season_players 
     LEFT JOIN players ON (season_players.playerid_f = players.playerid_p)
     LEFT JOIN handicaps ON (handicaps.playerid_f = players.playerid_p)
WHERE season_players.seasonid_f = '$currentSeason'
      AND season_players.teamid_f = '".$row["teamid_p"]."'
GROUP BY players.playerid_p
ORDER BY handicaps.handicap ASC, handicaps.added_date ASC
```

The `handicaps` table can have multiple entries per player for any reviews they have had.

I can't figure out how to make the latest handicap to be used for the ordering (something maybe to do with MAX on added_date?) yet at the same time if two or more handicaps are the same it order them by oldest registered first based on added_date.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of trying to figure out how to satisfy your needs in current query, wouldn't it be an option to  create a separate table, let's say "Handicaps_latest", which only stores player_id and required info of latest review. The reason for doing this is because you are only trying to get(columns in your select clause) the information about players and nothing really needed from handicaps table. In this case, a handicaps table with multiple entries per player might not be a good table to join. But considering that those data might be required in other logic, so leave them there and create a branch new table only storing latest review data could be an option for your case. But it requires some extra work apparently, that is, whenever you insert a new entry into your original handicpas table, a particular entry in handicaps_latest needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id,MAX(other_column) max_other_column FROM my_table GROUP BY id) y
    ON y.id = x.id
   AND y.max_other_column = x.other_column;
```